# Cosine similarity calculation between two matrices

Tags: python, matrix, cosine-similarity

I have a code to calculate cosine similarity between two matrices:

```
def cos_cdist_1(matrix, vector):
    v = vector.reshape(1, -1)
    return sp.distance.cdist(matrix, v, 'cosine').reshape(-1)


def cos_cdist_2(matrix1, matrix2):
    return sp.distance.cdist(matrix1, matrix2, 'cosine').reshape(-1)

list1 = [[1,1,1],[1,2,1]]
list2 = [[1,1,1],[1,2,1]]

matrix1 = np.asarray(list1)
matrix2 = np.asarray(list2)

results = []
for vector in matrix2:
    distance = cos_cdist_1(matrix1,vector)
    distance = np.asarray(distance)
    similarity = (1-distance).tolist()
    results.append(similarity)


dist_all = cos_cdist_2(matrix1, matrix2)
results2 = []
for item in dist_all:
    distance_result = np.asarray(item)
    similarity_result = (1-distance_result).tolist()
    results2.append(similarity_result)
```

`results` is

```
[[1.0000000000000002, 0.9428090415820635],
                     [0.9428090415820635, 1.0000000000000002]]
```

However, `results2` is `[1.0000000000000002, 0.9428090415820635, 0.9428090415820635, 1.0000000000000002]`

My ideal result is `results`, which means the result contains lists of similarity values, but I want to keep the calculation between two matrices instead of vector and matrix, any good idea?

Comment: Could you normalize the matrix columns and then AB' would be the similarity matrix. Use np.dot(A,B.T)

Comment: thanks for your comments, but I have to keep the matrix as it is, since it has other meaning

Answer (score 20):

```
In [75]: import scipy.spatial as sp
In [76]: 1 - sp.distance.cdist(matrix1, matrix2, 'cosine')
Out[76]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.94280904],
       [ 0.94280904,  1.        ]])
```

Therefore, you could eliminate the `for-loops` and replace it all with

```
results2 = 1 - sp.distance.cdist(matrix1, matrix2, 'cosine')
```

Comment: is there any faster way? I have 2 sets of vectors and I want to calculate the cosine similarity of these 2 sets.

Comment: Since the cosine function can assume values in the range [-1, 1], this approach provides incorrect values when the cosine similarity is negative.

Answer (score 3):

you can have a look at scikit learn's API for calculating cosine similarity: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html.

> Cosine similarity, or the cosine kernel, computes similarity as the
> normalized dot product of X and Y:
>
> **K(X, Y) = <X, Y> / (||X||*||Y||)**
>
> **X**: darray or sparse array, shape: (n_samples_X, n_features)
>
> **Y**: darray or sparse array, shape: (n_samples_Y, n_features)
> If None, the output will be the pairwise similarities between all
> samples in X.